# Using AVPlayer as input for AVCaptureSession?

Tags: ios, avplayer, avcapturesession

Is it possible to capture the output of the `AVPlayer` using `AVCaptureSession`? I believe it's possible but can't figure out how to go about using the `AVPlayer` as an input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot plug an `AVPlayer` into an `AVCaptureSession`, although you can get access to the player's video and audio in the form of `CVPixelBuffer`s and `AudioBufferList`s.

This is achieved via two APIs: `AVPlayerItemVideoOutput` for video and `MTAudioProcessingTap` for audio.

Despite being a c-api, `MTAudioProcessingTap` is easier to integrate as just like `AVCaptureSession`, it pushes you samples via a callback, while with `AVPlayerItemVideoOutput` you pull frames for a given time.
For this reason, if you want a `AVCaptureSession`-like experience (real-time, push), you should probably let the audio tap drive your frame-pulling.

There is some `AVPlayerItemVideoOutput` sample code in objective-c [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/AVBasicVideoOutput/Introduction/Intro.html) and in swift [here](https://github.com/ooper-shlab/AVBasicVideoOutput-Swift) and an example of using an `MTAudioProcessingTap` in swift [here](https://github.com/gchilds/MTAudioProcessingTap-in-Swift).

Comment: thanks a ton! that pointed me in the right direction. if you happen to know of any links that could help illustrate as well, i'd appreciate it.

Comment: Swift or objective c?

Comment: swift would be fantastic, but it doesn't matter. i can get the understanding from either. :) thanks!!!

Comment: added, only the tap is in swift